"Das Schlucken eines Löffels Zucker"
Hier (Why do we say ”die Rechte von Minderheiten”, but "eine Tasse Tee", without "von"?) habe ich nachgelesen:

Die Apposition steht immer im gleichen Kasus wie das Bezugswort, zu
dem sie gehört!

Im Satz

Sie trinkt eine Tasse heiße Schokolade.

stehen beide Substantive im Akkusativ. So weit, so gut - alles verständlich.
In einer Übungsgrammatik (in einem Kapitel, in dem das Thema Verbalstil → Nominalstil behandelt wird) steht:

Das Schlucken eines Löffels Zucker

Wenn ich vom oben stehenden Zitat ausgehe, habe ich nun ein Fragezeichen im Kopf: Warum wird Zucker nicht an Löffel angepasst? Warum heißt es nicht Das Schlucken eines Löffels Zuckers?
Vielen Dank!

... oder steht "Zucker" etwa im Genitiv Plural?

Quite similar question which one could also consider as duplicate. I'm not convinced, that the combination of amount and unit  is necessarily an apposition, the Partitive has some special properties, see Wikipedia.

In the German terminology it is indeed called an apposition, unfortunately.

Mit dem Ausdruck "Apposition" werden in der deutschen Grammatik traditionell leider zwei Sachen bezeichnet, die grammatisch ganz verschieden sind, siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition
Die Regel-Formulierung, die du zitiert hast, und auf eine andere Frage verlinkt ist, lässt sich dort auf folgende Webseite zurückverfolgen: https://deutschegrammatik20.de/attribute/die-apposition/ Dort geht es um einen anderen Typ von Beispielen, nämlich "lockere Apposition", etwas Ähnliches wie eine Parenthese. Dein Beispiel ist eine sogenannte "enge Apposition": Die Beziehung der beiden Wörter "Löffel" und "Zucker" ist äußerst eng, das wird manchmal als ein "Doppelkern" der Substantivgruppe bezeichnet. Dagegen ist die lockere Apposition, der "Erklärungszusatz", mit ihrer Kasus-Übereinstimmung grammatisch gerade das entgegengesetzte Extrem.
Warum es jetzt bei der engen Verbindung keine Kasus-Übereinstimmung gibt, ist eine interessante Frage, denkbar wäre es ja trotzdem. Es gibt auch Fälle, wo sie sich tatsächlich findet, etwa:

"Sie begnügte sich mit [einer Tasse] [schwarzem Kaffee]" (Dudengrammatik 2022, S. 446)

Die Dudengrammatik sagt, dass bei Appositionen, die nur aus einem einzelnen Wort bestehen, die Kasusübereinstimmung oft nicht auftritt (S. 447). Es gebe aber auch hier manchmal die Übereinstimmung: "Sie kam mit einem Korb Äpfel(n)".
Ich nehme an, Kasusregeln greifen eher, wenn eine ganze grammatische Ergänzung und ein klares Abhängigkeitsverhältnis vorliegt, so wie beim Objekt oder Genitiv-Attribut, also wo eine ganze Phrase (Wortgruppe) Ergänzung ist. Der Doppelkern einer engen Apposition ist mehr wie ein einziges Gesamtwort. Zudem ist das Auftreten des Genitivs im Deutschen oft eingeschränkter als die anderen Kasus, vielleicht gehört das Phänomen auch in diese Reihe (z.B. erscheint der Genitiv nach Präpositionen oft nicht, wenn nur ein einzelnes Substantiv folgt)
